# How to use folders in views with express app

Tags: express, pug

I have a pug template inside my views folder under `views/administration/assets/fixed-assets.pug`

My `default.pug` which the `fixed-assets.pug` extends from is in my root views folder.

When I try to render the `fixed-assets.pug` view it looks for the `default.pug` inside the `views/administration/assets/` directory rather than the views directory itself

Everything works fine if I take the `fixed-assets.pug` and place it in the views directory instead of the `views/administration/assets/` directory and update the route accordingly.

How can I tell express to look for the `default.pug` in the views directory and the `fixed-assets.pug` in the `views/administration/assets/` directory?

Here is my route

```
var express = require('express');
var secured = require('../lib/middleware/secured');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET fixed-assets page. */
router.get('/administration/fixed-assets', secured(), function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('administration/assets/fixed-assets', {
    title: 'Fixed Assets'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my `views/administration/assets/fixed-assets.pug`

```
extends default.pug

block scripts
  if !starter
    script(src='/js/main.js')

block view
  .animated.fadeIn
    h1 Fixed Assets
```

and this is the error I'm getting

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/usr/src/app/views/administration/assets/default.pug' at
>   /usr/src/app/views/administration/assets/fixed-assets.pug line 1

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where this file located `extends default.pug` ?

Answer (score 2):

In the docs for [Includes](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) it says:

> If the path is absolute (e.g., include /root.pug), it is resolved by
>   prepending options.basedir. Otherwise, paths are resolved relative to
>   the current file being compiled.

The explanation for that is in the [API Reference](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html):

> basedir: string The root directory of all absolute inclusion.

You can implement basedir globally like this in your main app.js/server.js file:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.locals.basedir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');
```