# How to Call Multiple File .pug in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I want to call several .pug files so that it runs dynamically. But I get an error.

```
res.render('layout');
res.render('body');
res.render('footer');
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this? I can't call multiple .pug files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call it using your pug files (NOT with your route files, but your pug files)

header.pug

```
nav.nav-top
    ul
        li.menu-item
            a(href='/').menu Home
            a(href='/dashboard').menu Dashboard
            a(href='/dashboard/thelist').menu thelist
            a(href='/login').menu Login
```

footer.pug

main.pug [layout file]. NOTE the include part (eg include ../part/header-top). My part folder is different than my layout folder. It just means include the pug file and it will get the content of your other pug file. Just put include pugfilename.

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title #{title} 23
        link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
        //- script(src='/js/main.js')
        //- script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js")
    body
        container.page
            include ../part/header-top
            include ../part/header-main
            h1 Hello main.pug
            block content
            br
            hr
            block kicker
        footer
            p Copyright &copy; 2019
        script(src='/js/main.js')
```

In your view pug file that's being rendered from your route. Notethe extends and then file location of your pug file layout file. I called my layout file main, so point to it on your side.Block content is the content of the page. It will put the block content into your layout page where it says block content.

```
extends ../../template/layout/main

block content
    h1 View
    a(href="/dashboard/thelist") The List
```

NOTE: Depending on your layout and your folder structure, yours will be different than mine!

If you want more help, you need to give details of your folder structure!

If you need more help, this is an example of my setup (its about mixin, but it deals with your problem of calling pug files): [Include pug mixin from other view folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481027/include-pug-mixin-from-other-view-folder/58037233#58037233)